# How do I get to clean a column of mixed user id formats, turning rows into integers?

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion, integer

I am struggling to clean a dataset, converting one column of mixed formats of user ids. Having checked, using the nunique() command, I can observe appr-ly 15K different users, all listed either as s123456-like numbers or as abbreviations like 'abcde'. How do I convert the different formats into a comparable numeric format that I can merge with other datasets?

I have this:

```
df1['Get s-number IDs']
    0          s200100
    1          s203288
    2           wasnur
    3           hdmfla
    4           hdmfla
                ...
    1048555    s164118
    1048556    s164118
    1048557    s164118
    1048558    s164118
    1048559    s164118
```

I'd love this:

```
df1['User Name']
    0          200100
    1          203288
    2          wasnur (replaced by e.g. a unique dummy integer value)
    3          hdmfla (replaced by e.g. a unique dummy integer value)
    4          hdmfla (replaced by e.g. a unique dummy integer value)
               ...
    1048555    164118
    1048556    164118
    1048557    164118
    1048558    164118
    1048559    164118
```

When applying various methods to extract either digits or forcing string objects into int dtype, I keep getting errors.

Once fixed the converted data/dtypes should still reflect the same number of unique values in the dataset as defined by the aforementioned nunique() method.

At the end of the day, I want to end up with a column of rows that I call User Name and then compare above data with another dataset to check that I am working with the valid user ids (as defined by my internal customer).

Alternatively, how do I simply remove the text-like abbrevations from the column rows?

Any help is appreciated, BR hubsandspokes

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the numeric value assigned to user names that don't begin with s to be consistent between runs, This is how I would approach your problem:
Given a dataframe df:

```
    Get s-number IDs
0   s200100
1   s203288
2   wasnur
3   hdmfla
4   hdmfla
5   s164118
6   s164118
7   s164119
8   s164108
9   s164118
```

To convert to unique integer IDs proceed as follows:

```
#    from secrets import choice    Removed, because random selection is no longer required
    class USERID:
        
        def __init__(self, idlen = 5):
            self._idln = idlen
            self._defids = dict()
            self._used = set()
            
        def getID(self, name):
            if name in self._defids.keys():
                return self._defids[name]
            return (self.computId(name))
        
        def computId(self, name):
            def translate(name):
                 Removed random selection option
#                nid = str(''.join(choice('0123456789') 
#                                       for i in range (self._idln)))            
#                while int(nid) in self._used or int(nid[0]) == 0:
#                    nid = str(''.join(choice('0123456789') 
#                                       for i in range (self._idln)))
                
                nid = str(hash(name))[:self._idlen)
                self._used.add(int(nid))
                self._defids[name] = int(nid)
                return int(nid)
                
                return 0           
            if name[0] == 's':
                try:
                    nid = int(name[1:])
                    self._used.add(nid)
                    self._defids[name] = nid
                    return nid
                except:
                    return translate(name)
            else:        
                return translate(name)  

Then you can execute:

    ugen = USERID(6)
    df['User Name'] = df.apply(lambda row: ugen.getID(row['Get s-number IDs']), axis= 1)
    df
```

Which yields:

```
    Get s-number IDs    User Name
0   s200100 200100
1   s203288 203288
2   wasnur  788680
3   hdmfla  391167
4   hdmfla  391167
5   s164118 164118
6   s164118 164118
7   s164119 164119
8   s164108 164108
9   s164118 164118
```

Comment: Hi, itprorh66 - I incorporated the new code, yet it does not deliver the result I am looking for....I really appreciate your contribution...;o) Am I doing something incorrect when the User Name column still projects the mixed user id formats? Thx, hubsandspokes

Comment: Okay looking over your input I see the name of the Column with mixed data is named 'Get s-number IDs' and the column you want to have the Unique Id's in is named 'User Name'.  Does the 'User Name' already exist in your df or should it be added?

Comment: I just updated my answer to better reflect your specific needs.

Comment: Thx, it seems to be working now, except for the fact that the dummy values, representing the string values, e.g. wasnur, change for every time I run the code. Is there a chance you can update the code to make the values the same every time or simply remove such row values? For now, the values seem changing randomly. Once again, I am very grateful for your contribution, BR hubsandspokes..;o)

Comment: The only way to preserve the computed values from one ru to the next would be to create a file containing the already defined values, then load this file before you attempt to clean the database.  I wrote the code with the assumption, you would only want to cleanup the database after all data is loaded.

Comment: Another approach to get close to the same values every time is to define a function that uniquely converts the name such as wasnur into a unique numeric.  The use of hash will create such a value, however it is longer than 6 digits.  If you only take the first 6, you will get close to a unique value but possibilities for duplication do exist.

Comment: Hi itprorh66 - that makes sense. I think the important part here is that I get to create a distinguishable variable that can be 'put away', i.e. I can make sure that I only get to look at data related to s-values. While I am a bit reluctant to the risk of creating duplicates, how am I then to deal with that function adjustment? - BR, hubsandspokes

Comment: Updated the answer to utilize hash of name. This will ensure names are constant numeric between runs but won't necessarily guarantee unique numeric

Comment: Hi, is there a chance you could assist me in solving the following issue as well? - thx, for your kind support, BR hubsandspokes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311234/how-do-visualize-a-list-of-counts-per-userids-logging-in-to-a-system-over-time-a

Comment: If this approach answers this question, I would appreciate you marking the question as answered