# How do I visualize a list of counts per userids logging in to a system over time AND with groups # of userids logging in 1,2, 3,...n times?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, count, visualization

How do I show in a table and a graph groups (measured in counts) of userids logging in 1, 2, 3, n times for the same time period? My point is to learn logging in patterns over time of the 'dipl line', thus investigating what groups to continue working with. Say we have a large group of dipl userids logging in only 1 time (e.g. 50), another less big group logging in twice (e.g. 35), a third logging in > 10 times during weeks 21 and 22 (e.g. 12). Essentially, it is a question of regrouping below table 1, showing the number of userids by count 1, 2, 3, ..14,...n.. Therefore,...

..I have this:

```
  time_series_data_dipl.index = time_series_data_dipl["Logon Time"]
  time_series_data_dipl['Year'] = time_series_data_dipl.index.year
  time_series_data_dipl['month'] = time_series_data_dipl.index.month
  time_series_data_dipl['day'] = time_series_data_dipl.index.day
  time_series_data_dipl['hour'] = time_series_data_dipl.index.hour
  time_series_data_dipl['week'] = time_series_data_dipl.index.week
  time_series_data_dipl['count'] = time_series_data_dipl["User Name"]

  number_of_logons_dipl = time_series_data_dipl.groupby(["week", "User Name"]).count()["count"].reset_index()

  print("\nnumber_of_logons_dipl")
  print(number_of_logons_dipl)

  plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 5))
  sns.lineplot(x="week", y="count", data=number_of_logons_dipl) # hue="User Name",
  plt.title("Fig. 6 - Logons per time unit - dipl")
  plt.show()
```

...getting this table:

Table 1

```
  number_of_logons_dipl
       week  User Name  count
  0       2     191446      3
  1      21     143257      6
  2      21     152780      1
  3      21     160055      1
  4      21     162844      1
  ..    ...        ...    ...
  99     22     200502      8
  100    22     200569     14
  101    22     200574      2
  102    22     200580      1
  103    22     201683      6
```

Table 2 (input):

```
  number_of_logons_dipl_test = number_of_logons_dipl.reset_index()
  
  print("\nnumber_of_logons_dipl_test")
  print(number_of_logons_dipl_test)
  
  print("\nnumber_of_logons_dipl_test['User Name'].unique()")
  print(number_of_logons_dipl_test['User Name'].unique())
  
  print("\nnumber_of_logons_dipl_test['day'].unique()")
  print(number_of_logons_dipl_test['day'].unique())
  
  del number_of_logons_dipl_test['index']
  
  number_of_logons_dipl_test_new = number_of_logons_dipl_test.groupby(by=["count", 'day'], dropna=False)['User Name'].value_counts()
  
  print("\nnumber_of_logons_dipl_test_new")
  print(number_of_logons_dipl_test_new)
```

Table 2 (output):

```
  number_of_logons_dipl_test_new
  count  day  User Name
  1      19   143257       1
              152780       1
              176470       1
              182935       1
              185438       1
                          ..
  4      26   195207       1
         28   186085       1
         29   182935       1
  5      22   195214       1
  6      20   185438       1
  Name: User Name, Length: 258, dtype: int64
```

...and this graph:

[image: Time series on table data - no activity until week 21]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to plot user name logins versus time?  Do you want to plot user_groups per unit time (where a user_group is based on frequency of log in}? Do you want to plot count of log ins per week?

Comment: I know, it is kind of difficult to explain, yet I want to show in a graph number of users logging in number of times for week 2, 3, 4 and up to week 22. In the graph presented it shows number of counts per week. Hope this makes my question a little clearer. So I guess it is something like what you already state, i.e. user_groups per unit time (where a user_group is based on frequency of log in} BR hubsandspokes

Comment: Hi itprorh66, after some thinking and rearranging I arrived at table 2 (edited in). This is what I am really after. Table indicates groups of users by how many counts over time these groups did. The final step is to show all the counts ('count') over time ('day') as per groups ('User Name'). Appears I get a strange graph. Btw, notice that I changed time unit to 'day' from 'week', but that does not mean anything. It can be changed back.